# font-face not working with .htaccess file

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess

I have a custom font that I am using for my website and the CSS looks like the following :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'roboto_condensed';
src: url('RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('RobotoCondensed-Regular-webfont.svg#roboto_condensedregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

and it works totally fine, all the places I want roboto to appear it does.  However, it starts to not function properly when I introduce my .htaccess file which looks like:

```
    ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./index.php?role=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/$ ./index.php?role=$1
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([\w\s\.\']+)&([\s\w\'\.]+)$ ./result.php?role=$1&champ1=$2&champ2=$3
```

now I'm not really the best at htaccess files but I do know that on the original server my website was on the above code worked fine together but now that I moved it over to a new server it is just showing the next font in line and not roboto at all.  Could this be problems with my apache settings or is there some obvious red flag with either the CSS I have or my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this under ExpiresActive On in `<IfModule mod_expires.c>`

```
ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access 1 month"
```